# Carregar DataSource de ComboBox usando método assíncrono

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, async

Tenho uma combo box de cidades que preencho ela todas as vezes que inicio meu formulário. Gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar a criar um método assíncrono utilizando `SqlDataAdapter` para preencher esta combo.

Comment: Faltam alguns detalhes sobre o que você precisa e sobre a implementação atual. Antes de mais nada: por que você precisa preencher o combo assincronamente?

Comment: Até aonde conheço sobre métodos assíncronos, eles liberam a thread principal e assim melhora o desempenho em alguns casos, certo? Pelo que entendo, neste caso poderia liberar o a inicialização do form, enquanto preenche a combo

Comment: Se a intenção é apenas não travar a thread principal, seu pensamento está correto. Mas este carregamento demora tanto assim a ponto de travar a thread principal? São tantos registros assim? Não seria o caso de rever a forma que você busca os dados no banco? Veja, talvez você esteja procurando a solução pra um problema que nem existe ou, talvez, o problema é outro.

Comment: No caso, estou listando as cidades para um cadastro de destinatários de um sistema de gerenciamento, e estou listando todas as cidades do país. Gostaria de tentar utilizar o async para, como disse, não travar a thread principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem mais detalhes sobre a atual implementação e sobre a real necessidade de preencher o combo assincronamente é difícil de tentar lhe ajudar. Se você der mais detalhes, eu posso adaptar a resposta para seu caso.

Imagino que seja isso que procuras:

```
private void QualquerForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    await PreencheCombo();
}

private Task PreencheCombo()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => cbCidades.DataSource = Cidades.FindAll()));
    });
}
```